# CALayer memory allocation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

My iPad application is displaying some weird behaviour. Have a few custom UIView's that use Core Graphics, and I'm finding that when the view is removed and dealloc is called, the memory for 'CALayer' stays active? Im using a drawer style application, so every time the view is presented the memory usage basically doubles. This is what I'm getting in Instruments, anybody have an idea as to why this might happen?

[image: Instruments output]

LayoutSubviews from VDCircuitHeadingIndicatorView

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Super
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Create arrow path and set label frames according to arrow direction
    if (self.arrowDirection == VDCircuitHeadingIndicatorArrowDirectionLeft) {
        self.arrow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint:
            CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width - (self.lineWidth * 2), self.bounds.size.height / 2) 
            toPoint:CGPointMake((self.lineWidth * 2), self.bounds.size.height / 2)  
            tailWidth:self.bounds.size.height / 1.75 headWidth:self.bounds.size.height - (self.lineWidth * 2) 
            headLength:ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH
        ];

        [self.headingLabel setFrame:
            CGRectMake(ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH * 1.05, (self.bounds.size.height - (self.bounds.size.height / 1.75)) / 2, 
            self.bounds.size.width - (ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH * 1.75), (self.bounds.size.height / 1.75))
        ];

    } else {

        self.arrow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArrowFromPoint:
            CGPointMake((self.lineWidth * 2), self.bounds.size.height / 2) 
            toPoint:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width - (self.lineWidth * 2), self.bounds.size.height / 2) 
            tailWidth:self.bounds.size.height / 1.75 
            headWidth:self.bounds.size.height - (self.lineWidth * 2) 
            headLength:ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH
        ];

        [self.headingLabel setFrame:
            CGRectMake(ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH / 1.5, (self.frame.size.height - (self.frame.size.height / 1.75)) / 2, 
            self.frame.size.width - (ARROW_HEAD_LENGTH * 1.75), (self.frame.size.height / 1.75))];

    }

    [self.headingLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:(self.bounds.size.height / 2)]];

    // Rotate view to rotation degrees value
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(self.rotation));

   // If we have rotated
   if (self.rotation != 0 && [self.superview isKindOfClass:[VDCircuitView class]])
   {
       // Get the x coord and the width of the superview
       float x = self.frame.origin.x;
       float superWidth = self.superview.frame.size.width;

       // If the view's x coord is less than half the width of the superview - set x to 0
       if (x < (superWidth / 2)) {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
       } else {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width - self.frame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
       }
}
```

DrawRect from VDCircuitHeadingIndicatorView

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Super
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self.arrow setLineWidth:self.lineWidth];

    // Set arrow path colour
    [self.lineColour setStroke];
    [self.arrowBackgroundColour setFill];

    // Stroke arrow path
    [self.arrow stroke];
    [self.arrow fill];
}
```

Comment: Probably you are not releasing all values. Paste a code from the views that are doing that.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski i've added the layousubviews and drawrect from VDCircuitHeadingIndicatorView, one of the views that has the problem. Im using arc just for info